# Solving a Convex and Linear Program

Tags: matlab, optimization, cplex, convex-optimization, cvx

[image]
  Hello all,
  I am very new to optimization. What could be the best approach to solve this problem? I have used cplex 
 to solve these ending up in the bay. Can any one guide me for possible solution using matlab. The code I used in Cplex

`dvar float avgrate;
maximize avgrate;`

`subject to{`

`forall (i in V)`

`avgrate <= (1/n)*(sum (a in N)((b[i][a]) * (log(1+((P*h0) /
                                                (sig*((H*H)+((x[i][a]-y[a])*(x[i][a]-y[a])) ) ) ) ))));`

`forall (a in N)
sum (i in V) b[i][a] <=1;}`

Comment: Hi, if you have a working model in OPL CPLEX, why do not you call it from Matlab ?

Comment: Can you share how to call model from matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to call OPL CPLEX from Matlab

```
command = 'oplrun model.mod data.dat';

[status, cmdout] = system(command);
```

which is part of [how to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)